# How to remove baseURL from axios.get request in node.js

Tags: node.js, axios

I am using Axios to get data from a url. When the url begins with http:// or https:// i get an error

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND <url> at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:50:26)
```

After researching i found that removing the http:// and https:// prefixes could fix this. But the problem is that Axios automatically includes these prefixes.

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to manually set the baseUrl like something below.

```
 {
  host: 'dropbox.com',
  path: '/s/ioedmud5dbc2bnu/1100.%20mobi.jpg?dl=1'
}
```

Comment: it's not clear actually what you want exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance), you can create a new instance of axios with a custom config.

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'dropbox.com'
});
```

You can then use that instance to make a request:

```
instance.get('/s/ioedmud5dbc2bnu/1100.%20mobi.jpg?dl=1').then(...).catch(...);
```